# how to find number that's divisible by a number in a given range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have this code:

```
generateMin = 150
generateMax = 250
if (current_level.world_shift * -1 % n == 0
        for n in range(generateMin, generateMax)):
    print("in range")
```

Which is checked at 100 FPS — as I move right/left `current_level.world_shift` is changed. However this code does not work. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: "Not working"? What is it not doing or doing?

Comment: `current_level.world_shift` its returning negative number always, thats why  i multiply it with -1, basically, if i move right `current_level.world_shift` increases + 2 every time i press right arrow key, if i press left arrow key, it decreases -2, i need to get random location, between min and max number, if  `range(generateMin, generateMax)` is dividable by `current_level.world_shift`, now 0 - 4000
Right now it returns "In range" every time `current_level.world_shift` changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?#generator-expressions) in an `if` statement like that. This is because initially a generator expression yields a new generator object and instances of most types are generally considered `True` (see [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in the documentation).

To do what you want I suggest you instead use the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#any) function. Doing so will be fast because it will stop soon as a `True` boolean sub-expression value is encountered.

Here's what I mean:

```
# a couple of things to allow dot syntax used in question to be used in answer
class Level: pass
current_level = Level()

current_level.world_shift = -175
generateMin = 150
generateMax = 250

if any(current_level.world_shift*-1 % n == 0
        for n in range(generateMin, generateMax)):
    print("in range")
```

`any()` will return `True` if `current_level.world_shift*-1` is evenly divisible by any number in the open-ended range (assuming that's what you're trying to determine). By open-ended I mean that the value `generateMax` will *not* be considered because `range(start, stop)` only covers the values from `start` to `stop-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the `range()` method. It doesn't create a random number, it creates a list of numbers in a particular range. E.g., `range(1,5)` yields `[1,2,3,4]`

```
import random
generateMin = 150
generateMax = 250
if (current_level.world_shift * -1 % random.randint(generateMin, generateMax) == 0):
        print("in range")
```

I think you were trying to have an assignment in the conditional, e.g., `if (n == 1 with n = 1)`, but mistakenly ended up using list comprehension, which always validated as `True`. I'm kind of amazed that didn't give a syntax error.

Python does not support assignment within a conditional, you'll need to assign before the if, or don't assign at all, like in the above code.

Comment: FWIW, `range(1,5)` yields `[1,2,3,4]` in Python 2 (or an iterator of those values in Python 3).